# Twisted: How to properly check that a request is finished

Tags: python, twisted

I'm creating an extremely simple Python script to serve one file to one person.  However, I cannot seem to figure out how to fire a callback when the request is finished or broken.  I was looking into [using deferreds](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/web/howto/web-in-60/interrupted.html) but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how they work.

As far as I can tell my server runs everything synchronously, so I would expect this to be enough:

```
class FileResource(resource.Resource):
  isLeaf = True

  def __init__(self, filepath):
    self.filepath = filepath
    self.filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

  def render_GET(self, request):
    print '%s: request opened (%s)' % (get_time(), request.getClientIP())
    request.setHeader('content-type', 'application/octet-stream')
    request.setHeader('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % self.filename)
    request.setHeader('content-length', os.path.getsize(self.filepath))
    with open(self.filepath, 'rb') as f:
      request.write(f.read())
      request.finish()
    print '%s: request closed (%s)' % (get_time(), request.getClientIP())
    return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```

But the second print fires immediately.  If anyone could point me in the right direct that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn when processing of the request is finished using `Request.notifyFinish`.  Unfortunately this doesn't tell you when the response has actually been sent over the network.  If you shut down the server when `Request.notifyFinish` tells you to then most likely you'll end up truncating the response.

Another more reliable but less convenient approach is to use `Connection: close` and notice when the HTTP implementation closes the underlying connection.  You can do this by hooking into the `connectionLost` method of the protocol (which is `HTTPChannel` for a Twisted Web server).